# How to verify X509Certificate with EC key using Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, x509certificate, elliptic-curve

With Bouncy Castle added as a provider, the following piece of code:

```
    private static boolean isSelfSigned(final X509Certificate cert) {

    try {

        final PublicKey key = cert.getPublicKey();

        cert.verify(key);

        return true;

    } catch (final RuntimeException re) {

        LOG.warn(re, "isSelfSigned: error.");
        return false;
    } catch (final GeneralSecurityException gse) {

        LOG.warn(gse, "isSelfSigned: error.");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Results in the following two errors depending on the implementation class of cert:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key (org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.BCECPublicKey) is not a RSAPublicKey instance
```

or

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key (sun.security.ec.ECPublicKeyImpl) is not a RSAPublicKey instance
```

Does Bouncy Castle not support verifying EC signed certificates?  There doesn't appear to be any parameters where I can indicate the keys are not RSA.  How do I verify an EC signed certificate using Bouncy Castle?

Answer (score 0):

This was a misunderstanding on my part.  The check fails because the certificate does in fact have an EC key, but the parent certificate has an RSA key.

Comment: Selfsigned certs (always) have subject = issuer; it's best to check that first before checking the signature.